# How to disable multiple http(s) request using request package in node js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, http

I'm trying to request an API using nodejs request package. In order to use the API, i need to request a refresh token API and it will provide me both new refresh token and access token.So what I've done, I request the balance with request API if failed due to `stat_code == 904` then I request for the new token and write it into a file.

Once the current access token expired I'll need to request a new access token with previous given refresh token. So when i trigger the request refresh token, there **are multiple request** within a second. The refresh token is changing once there a refresh token request coming into the API server.

I've done couple of research regarding this problem, the only closes thing that i found is in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/kleeRbjiioQ and i have implement the solution which mark the `agent:false` but still having the same issue.I use `process.hrtime()` for easy time referrer.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

var username = '';

request_api('john');

//request api function
function request_api(username){
    var username = username;
    var acc_token = fs.readFileSync('authentication/acc_token', 'utf8').replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
    var datetime = process.hrtime()

    console.log('request balance start '+ datetime)
    console.log('username ='+username);
    console.log('Access token ='+acc_token);

    request({
        url: 'https://sample.api/accbalance?', //URL to hit
        qs: {username:username, channel:'WEB'}, //Query string data
        method: 'GET',
        json: true,
        agent: false,
        pool: false,
        forever: false,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ acc_token , 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
    }, function (error, response, body) {
         var $ = cheerio.load(body, { xmlMode: true });
         var stat_code = $('ams\\:code').html();

         //Check for error
         if(error){
             return console.log('Error:', error);
         }

         //Check for right status code
         else if(response.statusCode == 401 && stat_code == 904){  
            //904 response timeout 
            console.log('status code '+response.statusCode+ ' and status code'+ stat_code)
            async.waterfall([
                    request_token,
                    request_api(username)
                ], function (error) {
                    if (error) {
                        //handle readFile error or processFile error here
                    }
                });

            }
            else {
                console.log('This is your balance' +body.content.pps.balance);
                console.log('This is your expiry date' +body.content.pps.activestop);
            }
        }
    )
};

//request for API refresh token 
function request_token(){
    var scope = 'SANDBOX'
    var consumer_key = 'key'
    var consumer_secret = 'secret'
    var en_auth_code = new Buffer(consumer_key + ':' + consumer_secret).toString('base64');
    var ref_token = fs.readFileSync('authentication/ref_token', 'utf8').replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
    var datetime = process.hrtime()

    console.log('request refresh token start '+ datetime)
    console.log('refresh token = '+ ref_token)

    request({
    url: 'https://sample.api/token?', //URL to hit
    qs: {grant_type:'refresh_token', refresh_token:ref_token ,scope:scope }, //Query string data
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    agent: false,
    pool: false,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+ en_auth_code, 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    }, function(error, response, body){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else if(response.statusCode == 200){
            console.log(response.statusCode, body);

            fs.writeFileSync('authentication/acc_token', body.access_token, 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                });
            console.log('Access token is saved! '+ body.access_token);

            fs.writeFileSync('authentication/ref_token', body.refresh_token, 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                });
            console.log('Refresh token is saved! '+ body.refresh_token);
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode+'\n'+body)
        }
    });
};
```

the output that I've received after running the code was something like this

```
request balance start 411093,450855461 //1st api request
username =john
Access token =b212ae55ea6cbb35421679e75f91b0
status code 401 and status code900904
request balance start 411093,814554860  //2nd api request suddenly trigger
username =john
Access token =b212ae55ea6cbb35421679e75f91b0
request refresh token start 411093,816874643
refresh token = 9e52f688428e3c8e8a1a0bb81e48182
200 { expires_in: 86400,
  refresh_token: '7add853045e2d2534e4679d9d719eef9',
  access_token: '414a4d7f2ca9f337a39f8ad2bc412b4' }
Access token is saved! 414a4d7f2ca9f337a39f8ad2bc412b4
Refresh token is saved! 7add853045e2d2534e4679d9d719eef9
status code 401 and status code900904
request balance start 411093,884380787
username =john
Access token =414a4d7f2ca9f337a39f8ad2bc412b4
request refresh token start 411093,885204220
refresh token = 7add853045e2d2534e4679d9d719eef9
200 { 
  expires_in: 86400,
  refresh_token: '68798d3d73b7359b8463d8174ae63',
  access_token: '6cfe65873cf2d46c99616360a76e34ef' }
Access token is saved! 6cfe65873cf2d46c99616360a76e34ef
Refresh token is saved! 68798d3d73b7359b8463d8174ae63
status code 401 and status code900904
request balance start 411093,986352118
username =john
Access token =6cfe65873cf2d46c99616360a76e34ef
request refresh token start 411093,987246880
refresh token = 68798d3d73b7359b8463d8174ae63
200 { 
  expires_in: 86400,
  refresh_token: 'ec4758d42bc960d05cec7174da502764',
  access_token: '2cc27b78c59267f7dee5ac1aed89c7a' }
Access token is saved! 2cc27b78c59267f7dee5ac1aed89c7a
Refresh token is saved! ec4758d42bc960d05cec7174da502764
status code 401 and status code900904
request balance start 411094,154365494
username =john
Access token =2cc27b78c59267f7dee5ac1aed89c7a
request refresh token start 411094,154877335
refresh token = ec4758d42bc960d05cec7174da502764
200 { 
  expires_in: 86400,
  refresh_token: '50a160aceeac3e251d7e287b99ffa',
  access_token: 'fddb51934f5d7de38a8469aefc23' }
Access token is saved! fddb51934f5d7de38a8469aefc23
Refresh token is saved! 50a160aceeac3e251d7e287b99ffa
status code 401 and status code900904
request balance start 411094,248689543
username =john
Access token =fddb51934f5d7de38a8469aefc23
request refresh token start 411094,253453940
refresh token = 50a160aceeac3e251d7e287b99ffa
200 { 
  expires_in: 86400,
  refresh_token: 'd3123ac463e754afd41c7a7065f4b9fa',
  access_token: 'adec764091897b591aecfa3db6d44cc' }
Access token is saved! adec764091897b591aecfa3db6d44cc
Refresh token is saved! d3123ac463e754afd41c7a7065f4b9fa
status code 401 and status code900904
request balance start 411094,392741956
username =john
Access token =adec764091897b591aecfa3db6d44cc
request refresh token start 411094,393600819
refresh token = d3123ac463e754afd41c7a7065f4b9fa
200 { 
  expires_in: 86400,
  refresh_token: 'dfdb3434f4993da5e271570b994d126',
  access_token: '6e53e9746ea9df7a5633f8e96923d5' }
Access token is saved! 6e53e9746ea9df7a5633f8e96923d5
Refresh token is saved! dfdb3434f4993da5e271570b994d126
status code 401 and status code900904
request balance start 411094,478962663
username =john
Access token =6e53e9746ea9df7a5633f8e96923d5
request refresh token start 411094,479420015
refresh token = dfdb3434f4993da5e271570b994d126
200 { 
  expires_in: 86400,
  refresh_token: '5f137193cdac6e2ec13fe38daf6eba70',
  access_token: '96687f1eb16094d53ee08abe1d5d40db' }
Access token is saved! 96687f1eb16094d53ee08abe1d5d40db
Refresh token is saved! 5f137193cdac6e2ec13fe38daf6eba70
This is your prepaid 1329438
This is your expiry date 20180313
```

It seems that the synchronous function got mix up I guess. Btw I'm trying to implement this in the server side. The feedback of the **body** api server would be in json file as shown below.

```
{
    "resCode": "200",
    "resDesc": "Operation successfully.",
    "content": {
        "pps": {
            "balance": "1440198",
            "activestop": "20180313"
        },
        "paid": "0"
    }
}
```

the success refresh token **body** would be in json file as shown in below code.

```
{
    "expires_in": 86400,
    "refresh_token": "55379e18b6c6ce1ca6b39a77f15549a3",
    "access_token": "7c6af5939cbecd7ccd83acf57b40bb"
}
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost a week of trying, I decide to change my code from using request package to using request-promise and it work!! So far I don't have multiple request to the API server and the code works fine. So i just wanted to share the code and hopefully it can help other people too.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request-promise');

request_api_promise('john')
.then((result) => {
console.log(result);
})
.catch((error) => {
console.log(error);
})

//request for API feature
function request_api_promise(username) {

    let acc_token = fs.readFileSync('authentication/acc_token', 'utf8').replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
    let datetime = process.hrtime() //Calculate time start

    console.log('request balance start =' + datetime)
    console.log('username =' + username);
    console.log('Access token =' + acc_token);

    let option = {
    url: 'https://sample.api/accbalance?', //URL to hit
    qs: {
        username: username,
        channel: 'WEB'
    }, //Query string data
    method: 'GET',
    json: true,
    agent: false,
    pool: false,
    forever: false,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + acc_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
    }

    return request(option)
    .then((response) => {

         return ({
                balance: response.body.content.pps.balance,
                expiry_date: response.body.content.pps.activestop
            }) 

    })
    .catch((error) => {
        let $ = cheerio.load(error.response.body, {
            xmlMode: true
        });
        let stat_code = $('ams\\:code').html();

        if (error.statusCode == 401 && stat_code == 904) {

            console.log('Error: status code ' + error.statusCode + ' stat_code code ' + stat_code)
            return request_token_promise().then(() => request_api_promise(username))
        }
        console.log(error)
    })
}

//request for API refresh token 
function request_token_promise() {
    let scope = 'SANDBOX'
    let consumer_key = 'key'
    let consumer_secret = 'secret'
    let en_auth_code = new Buffer(consumer_key + ':' + consumer_secret).toString('base64');
    let ref_token = fs.readFileSync('authentication/ref_token', 'utf8').replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
    let datetime = process.hrtime()

    console.log('request refresh token start = ' + datetime)
    console.log('refresh token = ' + ref_token)

    let option = {
    url: 'https://sample.api/token?', //URL to hit
    qs: {
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: ref_token,
        scope: scope
    }, //Query string data
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    agent: false,
    pool: false,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + en_auth_code,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
    }

    return request(option)
    .then((response) => {

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            console.log(response.body);

            fs.writeFileSync('authentication/acc_token', response.body.access_token, 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
            console.log('Access token is saved! ' + response.body.access_token);

            fs.writeFileSync('authentication/ref_token', response.body.refresh_token, 'utf8', (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
            console.log('Refresh token is saved! ' + response.body.refresh_token);

        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            console.log(response.body);
        }
    })
};
```

below are the output.

```
request balance start =849919,250316580
username =john
Access token =8d729facf8cc22fa7ad676c7699d2
status code 401 anderrorus code 904
request refresh token start = 849919,417863982
refresh token = c4e674d0a68ba39f29f476b18bc5ed
200
{ 
  expires_in: 86400,
  refresh_token: '7c82da4ed9e6fb593e6fadd0c9fd30da',
  access_token: '968472961db5274852afcee7431ed3f5' }
Access token is saved! 968472961db5274852afcee7431ed3f5
Refresh token is saved! 7c82da4ed9e6fb593e6fadd0c9fd30da
request balance start =849919,503441510
username =john
Access token =968472961db5274852afcee7431ed3f5
{ balance: '1329438', expiry_date: '20180313' }
```

But still I do know what wrong with the first set of code. Would be good if you guys can point the problem of my 1st code.